# Passing variables between threads in Java

Tags: java, synchronization

I have 10 identical threads (differentiated only by primary key from 1 to 10) that I create in the main class. In each thread I need to read field in the previous thread i.e. in thread 5 I need to read this field in thread 4. The question is how can I do it?

```
public class Player extends Thread {

private Integer playerNumber;

public char lastDigit;

public Player(Integer playerNumber) {
    super();
    this.playerNumber = playerNumber;
}

public synchronized char getDigit(){
    return this.lastDigit;
}

public synchronized void setDigit(char digit){
    massage += digit;
    this.lastDigit = digit;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run(){

}
```

I need to read the lastDigit field.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lots of options :) By default, java collections aren't syncronized:

You could make a LinkedBlockingQueue in a static variable/class:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html

You could wrap one of the many java collections with the following:

- Collections.synchronizedMap(..)
- Collections.synchronizedList(..)
- Collections.synchronizedSet(..)

If you don't mind some complication, but are concerned about GC overhead, use Exchanger (I'd recommend this for your situation):

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html

If you reallly want to go all out and performance is a *major* concern, you could use the Disrupter framework (not for the feint of heart):

- http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/

Comment: Pretty much my favourite class :)

Comment: Very true, I've edited to say Exchanger is probably the best suited for his app. With Exchanger, the exchange method blocks until a 'handshake' between the threads happens. So as long as he always try to exchange with the previous thread first (think dining philosophers problem) it's a good choice :)

Comment: Hi exabrial. I tried the Exchanger and it did the work for me. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome, that's why we're here. be sure to check the checkmark to mark as accepted ;) ;)

Comment: wowow..thanks you..I have had a similar problem but didn't know about disruptor..I thought I had to use a external database to share state between threads, which made my program so slow it was useless.  Thanks for the great answer, my program is being raisen from the dead.